# Fixing issue with program that calculates grade average with option of dropping lowest grade

Tags: python

I need to create a program that calculates grade averages and provides the option of dropping the lowest grade. The program must allow the user to enter the number of students and number of grades per student. I keep getting "'int' object is not iterable" with respect to the "lowest" component. Please help.

```
def main():

    num_students=eval(input("Please enter the number of students you will have grades for: "))
    num_grades=eval(input("Please enter the number of grades per student: "))
    gcounter=0
    scounter=1
    drop=input("Do you wish to drop the lowest grade? Type yes or no: ")

    if drop=="no" or drop=="No" or drop=="n" or drop=="N":
        while scounter<=num_students:
            name=input("Please enter the student's name: ")
            grades_total=0
            while gcounter<num_grades:
                getgrade=eval(input("Enter grade: "))
                grades_total=grades_total+getgrade
                gcounter=gcounter+1

            print("The average grade for ", name, "is ", grades_total/gcounter)
            num_students=num_students-1
            scounter=scounter+1
            gcounter=0


    elif drop=="yes" or drop=="Yes" or drop=="y" or drop=="Y":
        while scounter<=num_students:
            name=input("Please enter the student's name: ")
            grades_total=0
            while gcounter<num_grades:
                getgrade=eval(input("Enter grade, including the lowest: "))
                lowest = min(getgrade)
                grades_total=grades_total+(getgrade-lowest)
                gcounter=gcounter+1

            print("The average grade for ", name, "is ", grades_total/(gcounter-1))
            num_students=num_students-1
            scounter=scounter+1
            gcounter=0
main()
```

Comment: `getgrade` is whatever was entered, not a list of grades, so taking the minimum doesn't make sense. Also `eval` is a dangerous choice here--you're accepting arbitrary user input. You're expecting either an int or a float, so cast to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line `lowest = min(getgrade)`. The `min` function expects to be passed an iterable argument, like a list or tuple. You're giving it a single number (assuming that what you typed in at the prompt). That can't work. You either need to put all the grades into a list first, then call `min` on it, or you need to do your checking of each grade differently (for instance, using `<` to test each grade against the previous minimum, which you'd probably need to initialize to something absurdly large, like `float('inf')`).

You certanly don't want to be subtracting the minimum value on every iteration. The simplest approach is to do that only at the end, after you've added up all the values (including the minimum):

```
        grades_total = 0
        lowest_grade = float('inf')                # initialize lowest_grade to infinity
        while gcounter < num_grades:               # this could be a `for` loop
            getgrade = int(input("Enter grade, including the lowest: "))
            grades_total += getgrade               # don't subtract minimum any more here
            gcounter += 1
            if getgrade < lowest_grade:            # check for minimum
                lowest_grade = getgrade
        grade_total -= lowest_grade                # subtract mimimum outside the loop
```

I'd also strongly recommend against using `eval` on user input, as that function would allow the user to type in *any valid Python expression* which your code would then run. You can use `int` to convert a string to an integer, usually, which it looks like is all you need. If you really do need to parse more complicated data structures like lists or tuples in one go, use `ast.literal_eval` from the standard library.

Comment: Would you please tell me what your solution is? I'm really confused and still don't understand what I need to do.

Comment: Alright, I've added some code. Making a list of grades might be a bit cleaner, but it would have involved changing more of the code. This approach (adding up and counting the values as you get them) works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`, as `eval` poses security risks.

Regarding your error, your error originates from these lines:

```
getgrade = eval(input("Enter grade, including the lowest: "))
lowest = min(getgrade)
```

The `min` function [takes an iterable as input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min). If `getgrade` is an integer or not an iterable, e.g. `tuple`, `list`, `set`, then you can expect an error each time this line is reached.

You can correct this by asking for each grade one by one and forming a list, or have the user input a list such as `"[55, 65, 70, 82]"`. This will have knock-on effects for your entire script, so you should decide how to approach your data types from the start.